# How can I access what variables are being imported in a perl module?

Tags: perl

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
use Foo::Bar $baz, qw/one two three/;
```

and then, inside a package

```
package Foo::Bar;

# probably do something magic here

sub do_something {
     # access $baz and 'one', 'two' and 'three' 
}
```

I remember seeing it done in a module and thinking it was a cool thing. Now I'd like to do it myself, and can't find the module anymore.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? In most cases you will probably really want to do something else. ;)

Comment: But if you do want to do this, look at the code for e.g. Data::Printer or Test::DBIx::Class. Those do this with config hashes on import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to pass data to a module you will need to write your own [`import`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/import.html) sub, as in the below example.

---

```
# Foo.pm
package Foo;

use Data::Dumper;

sub import {
    my $package = shift;
    my @data = @_;

    print STDERR Dumper \@data;
}

1;
```

```
# foo.pl
use Foo qw/hello world/;
```

---

```
$VAR1 = [
          'hello',
          'world'
        ];
```